# How do i get the rowposition for an Select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, row

Hi my Table looks like

```
Id  Header  Mo  RefId
 1  Header2 45   1
 4  Header2 10   1
 7  Header1  1   5
 8  Header2  2   5
 9  Header3 77   5
12  Header5 11   2
13  Header9 55   5
14  Header2 22   2
```

if i select all records `where RefId 5`

My desired result looks like

```
Pos Header  Mo RefId
 1  Header1  1   5
 2  Header2  2   5
 3  Header3 77   5
 4  Header9 55   5
```

Here the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b01b/2) for Testing

---

**Update**

Like you may see i try to get the row position from my resultset so is there some way to do this? and how performant will it be

i'm using **SQL Server 2008 R2**

Comment: which dbms do you use ?

Comment: Row position? The row num in the database? What database? Oracle?

Comment: @NeillVerreynne i add my Database

Comment: why is the 4th row in your desired result ? That makes no sense

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks, that was a typo

Comment: I have to shake my head on this one, but we all have to start from somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MSSQL 2008 approach.

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by (select null)) AS Pos, Header,Mo,RefId
FROM Table1
WHERE RefId =5
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately the result does not match [SQLFiddel](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b01b/13). Like you may can see my Pos goes `from 1 to 5` your Pos are `from 3 to 7`

Comment: Missunderstanding from my part. Updated the query. Also, you only have 4 rows with RefId = 5, so this example goes from 1 to 4

Comment: ah yes that was a typo in my question where i end up with 5 items as result :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify any `DBMS`, here how you could do it with `Oracle` or `MSSql`

```
select * from (select row_number() over(order by id) as Pos, Header, Mo, RefId from yourTable) x;
```

Now, here how you could do it with `MySQL`

```
SELECT @pos:=@pos+1 AS Pos, Header, Mo, RefId 
  FROM yourTable
  ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: @WiiMaxx I'm pretty sure the oracle one will works on MSSql, try it.

Comment: reason this doesn't work is that you have not named the tabel in your first query. Add X before semicolon and it will work

Comment: thanks for your effort (+1), but Peter's solution is the only one which works in MSSQL 2008, at least in SQLFiddle

Comment: @WiiMaxx You're welcome :). However, mine works too, the only thing I ommit is the condition where `refId = 5` as I simply wanted to give ways of selecting the rownum.

Comment: oh i see i missed `yourTable` which should be `Table1` , my bad :(